# jQuery : Append a non-breaking space to content of Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, textarea, line-breaks

I am trying to append a spacebar to the contents of a Textarea but this causes line break in the contents of the textarea. I am using  `$("#Textarea").val($("#Textarea").val()+data)` to append some data which works perfectly but then I try to append a space using the same  `$("#Textarea").val($("#Textarea").val()+" ")` and it simply causes line break. How can I insert a non-breaking space ?

Comment: Works perfectly as far as I can tell (http://jsbin.com/juxaroyoyo/edit?html,js,output) Can you add some snippets?

Comment: you can change the css white-space property of the textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the unicode non breaking space

```js
document.querySelector("#textarea1").value = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\u00A012345"
document.querySelector("#textarea2").value = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 012345"
```

```html
<label for="textarea1">Non Breaking</label> <textarea id="textarea1" style="width:220px"></textarea>
<br/>
<label for="textarea2">Breaking</label> <textarea id="textarea2" style="width:220px"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML tags for Text Area seems to be like:

```
<textarea id="TextArea">
Some Content
</textArea>
```

which appends a new line to your textarea by default. If you write make your markup like:

```
<textarea>Hello World</textarea>
```

your issue will be resolved!
Here is working example:

```
<html>
<body>
<textarea id="Textarea">Hello WOrld</textarea>
<button id="click-me">
Click Me! Everything is allright
</button>

<hr />
<textarea id="Textarea2">
Hello WOrld
</textarea>
<button id="click-me-2">
Click Me!Something is wrong!
</button>
</body>
</html
<script>
$('#click-me').click(function(){
$('#Textarea').val($('#Textarea').val() + " ");


});

$('#click-me-2').click(function(){
$('#Textarea2').val($('#Textarea2').val() + " ");


});
</script>
```